# How can I use Amazon product advertising API for India?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-product-advertising-api

I am sure many must have faced this issue
I have been trying to establish a affiliate website for amazon.
While trying to fetch its products though API i get this error
Invalid Country-Code: in! Possible Country-Codes: de, com, co.uk, ca, fr, co.jp, it, cn, es

so any idea who has implemented this already  ?

Comment: are you using any library?

Answer (score 2):

find code in  AmazonECS.class.php file

private $possibleLocations = array('de', 'com', 'co.uk', 'ca', 'fr', 'co.jp', 'it', 'cn', 'es');

Add "in" in above array

or simply replace with

private $possibleLocations = array('de', 'com', 'co.uk', 'ca', 'fr', 'co.jp', 'it', 'cn', 'es','in');

you will get the product list from amazon.in

Answer (score 0):

I don't get that error, I'm using the [exeu/apai-io](https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io) library. From your error message, it looks like you're using the old version of that library [exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library](https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library).

Try upgrading to the new version as it supports both `in` and `com.br`.

*FWIW, in hundreds of API requests for products that exist in all (or most of) the other Amazon stores, I've yet to get any results for an ASIN lookup from either `in` or `com.br`.*